# Why gcc is not using S16-S31 registers of Cortex M7?

Tags: gcc, arm, cortex-m, fpu

Cortex M7 with the FPv5 extension has 32 single precision floating point registers (or 16 double precision registers).
GCC `version 10.3.1 20210824 (release) (GNU Arm Embedded Toolchain 10.3-2021.10)` seems to generate code that uses only the first 16 single precision registers. Why is it so? Is there a way to make it use the other half, when only single precision math is used?

I'm compiling with `-mcpu=cortex-m7 -mfpu=fpv5-sp-d16 -mfp16-format=ieee`

Comment: what did the gnu folk say when you asked?

Comment: what does the calling convention say (ABI)?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [No FPU support with gcc for ARM Cortex M?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/66535809/no-fpu-support-with-gcc-for-arm-cortex-m)

Comment: `-d16` in the command you posted means "only 16 registers".  It is doing what you told it.

Answer (score 0):

Ok, I was actually wrong, gcc does emit code that uses these S16-S31 registers with these flags. Just not in the function I was focused on. Apparently it decided they are of no use there. Optimization info does not cover such details, it seems.
I guess the "-d16" part of the flag refers to 16 double precision registers.